# Receive bluetooth data in whole app

Tags: android, bluetooth

i develop an Android-Bluetooth App with 3-4 Activitys. Now i have to receive bluetooth data in any of these activitys.
I think i have to implement a Service which contains a BroadcastReceiver which listens to incoming BlueTooth Data and send a Broadcast, but i don't know how to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your own BroadcastReceiver. So, when your LocalService receive a data, it will notify using sendBroadcast method. Your activities should register the specific BrodcastReceiver.

**In your Service**

Notify about received messages:

```
public void onMessageReceived(String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_BLUETOOTH_MESSAGE);
    intent.putExtra(BLUETOOTH_MESSAGE_CONTENT, message);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

**On each activity**

Registering the broadcast receiver:

```
registerReceiver(messageReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(ACTION_BLUETOOTH_MESSAGE));
```

Implementation of the broadcast receiver:

```
private BroadcastReceiver messageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(BLUETOOTH_MESSAGE_CONTENT);
    //Do something you want 
    }
};
```

Comment: So... my LocalService extends Service... do i have to extend from something else that it works? Do i need to specify in my AndroidManifest.xml more than '<service android:name=".LocalService" />' ?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Extends from Service and add that line in your manifest. After, start your service. More details:http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: All i have to do is to add the "onMessageReceived(...)" in my 'LocalService extends Service'?! Nothing else? How does the Service know what kind of Messages he receives?

Comment: No, you must implement a mechanis of messages exchange using bluetooth . So when one device receive a message using your mechanim, the onReceivedMessage should be called. Take a look at: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html . Furthermore, there is a bluetooth example(BluetoothChat) in the Adroid SDK, that is implements a exchange message mechanism.